# In the navigation bar, how to use shorter words to indicate the search engine?

Tags: firefox, search

In Firefox, typing non-URL in the navigation bar will lead to the default search engine searching for the thing typed in. Firefox also provides a way to quick switch the search engine for the current search. For example, if I type `google superuser` in the navigation bar, it will use google as the search engine, regardless of the default search engine.

How can I make that indicator shorter, e.g., instead of typing `google`, just type `g` as the first word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My firefox language is Danish and I don't know how to change it - Anyway, here is how to do it:

Go to Settings and press on this in the side menu:

[image: Search]

Then you should see a screen like this:

[image: Search menu]

Here you can enter "Stikord" or Keywords in english. Try typing in g, like I have. Now you should be able to use google search by just typing g before your search.

Example:

[image: Example of google search]